# Resolve location dependency warning in React useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs

I have a `useEffect` that I would like to execute only the first time in a React component. I am using `location.pathname` in the `useEffect`, if I leave the array dependencies empty, I get this warning:

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'location.pathname'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

If I include the dependency, `useEffect` will be executed each time the user navigates.

I see many people telling that the warning is just a potential problem, but if you know what you are doing, you can just simply ignore it, or disable the warning with `// eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`.

I have been reading about this problem, I know that for functions I should use `useCallback`. What would be the equivalent for this case?

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

// Inside component

  const location = useLocation();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (location.pathname === VIEWS.initial) {
      setChecked(false);
    }
  }, []);
```

What would be the most correct solution to this problem?

Comment: It depends on what is inside the `useLocation` is it async? If so, I'd suggest adding the `location.pathname` as a dependency. Otherwise, you are right and it is just a potential problem.

Comment: `location.pathname` is from React Router. If I add it as dependency, each time there is a navigation in the app, useEffect will be executed again. I tested it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with `useRef`. It seems working fine, warning disappeared:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useRef } from 'react';

// Inside component

  const location = useLocation();
  const initialView = useRef(location.pathname);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (initialView.current === VIEWS.initial) {
      setChecked(false);
    }
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting the initial value in `useState` instead of `useEffect`:

```
const location = useLocation();
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(location.pathname === VIEWS.initial)
```

If you really want to set the state on mount via `useEffect`, the least verbose alternative would be to suppress the warning with a comment. However, if you at a later point extend this effect with more logic, you run the risk of encountering cryptic bugs regarding stale data that this warning might have prevented.

The third way would be to make sure that the effect is only run once while keeping the `location.pathname` dependency:

```
  const [hasMounted, setHasMounted] = useState(false)
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!hasMounted && location.pathname === VIEWS.initial) {
      setChecked(false);
      setHasMounted(true);
    }
  }, [location.pathname, hasMounted]);
```

This is in my opinion not advisable because of poor readability and unnecessary complexity compared to my first suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

```
const location = useLocation();
  useEffect(() => {
    
    if ((location.pathname)&&location.pathname === VIEWS.initial) {
      setChecked(false);
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are proposing. `location.pathname` exists, it is provided by `useLocation` hook from react router.

Comment: Yes, definitely . You can use that too . It is just one method from which your problem must get solved